# How to play a game with two robots

Tags: probability, game-theory

Imagine two robots on the number line starting at position $0$. If you choose one of the robots it goes forward one step with prob $p$ and backwards one step with prob $1-p$ with $p>1/2$. You want to get either one of the robots to the point 10 with minimum total cost. The cost is the sum of the square of the number of steps each robot has taken.

At each step you choose to move one of the two robots. How do you best play the game to minimise the expected cost?

The obvious strategy of always picking the robot closest to 10 has the the problem that more steps might have been taken by that robot, so increasing the number of steps by one will be more expensive than moving the robot that is further away.  That is because the cost is the sum of the square of the number of steps taken by each robot.

For example, say robot 1 has moved 5 steps left and 5 right and robot 2 has moved one step to -1. Moving robot 2 increases the cost by $2^2-1^1=3$ whereas moving robot 1 increases the cost by $11^2-10^2=21$ so it might be better to move the robot that was further from the destination.

**UPDATE**

Changed walk to be biased to ensure finite expected time to the destination.

Comment: Is there ever a reason to move the robot furthest from the finish line?

Comment: This post is too terse.  The "obvious" idea is to stick with the one that's closest to the end.  Maybe that's wrong, but it would be instructive to see an instance in which it was sub-optimal.  Surely you have worked that case out, no?

Comment: Post edit:  that objection does not make  apparent sense, since at some point you have to move the closer robot.  Sure the other robot might have "cheaper" steps but who cares since the best you can hope for is that someday they might be on the same spot, and then you still have to move from there.

Comment: @lulu say robot 1 has moved 5 steps left and 5 right and robot 2 has not moved at all. Moving robot 2 increases the cost by 1 but moving robot 1 increases the cost by 21 even though they are both in the same position.

Comment: @lulu does my edit clear things up?

Comment: The bigger problem is that the various expectations don't converge.  I can see where, if you have moved robot $A$ a million times back and forth, you might want to start moving $B$, but it's hard to quantify that.

Comment: +1: to your question.  I agree that in the situation where the closer robot has made a significantly greater number of steps, there does not seem to be an obvious answer.  In my opinion, the only way to answer this question is to compute the expected number of steps that each robot needs to get to the target, and then compute the expected penalty that each robot will incur, going to the target.  Further, this computation needs to be re-assessed each time that a move fails to move a robot in the right direction.  ...see next comment

Comment: I think that this is a problem for someone with a greater knowledge of Probability Theory than I have.

Comment: This is not possible as stated; the expected cost is $\infty$, because the expected number of steps to go from $0$ to $10$ is $\infty$ for a simple random walk. Perhaps you meant for the robots to enter the set $\{-10, 10\}$ instead?

Comment: It seems that some info about the starting point(s) of the robots is missing. Is it assumed to be $0$, for both robots? Because without that knowledge the $p>1/2$ correction seems arbitrary and counterproductive, when starting points are $> 10$.

Comment: @Ingix. They both start at $0$.